# Different digest from sha1 in JS and Python?

Tags: javascript, python, hash, encode, sha1

I've been stuck in this for a while, for the life of me.

I have this thing in python3

```py
msg = "6NmByERB9ZDJX9OKDtIzpGl8ei7KBiYI"+"\n"+"1623776851607"+"\n"+"/api2/v2/users/me"+"\n"+"0"
message = msg.encode('utf-8')
hash_object = hashlib.sha1(message)
sha_1_sign = hash_object.hexdigest()
print(sha_1_sign)
# 4ff521a9b87ddd0dea00a842f8f5d72819f9df0a
```

but I cannot **GET THIS SAME HASH** in NodeJS, I've tried a lot of solutions;
at first I though it was the first part, the encode to utf-8, because printing that was returning different results, but it seems like that's not it, it was just different representation of the same string.

My approach in JS:

```
const crypto = require('crypto') // maybe another library that works in browser? 
const msg = "6NmByERB9ZDJX9OKDtIzpGl8ei7KBiYI"+"\n"+"1623776851607"+"\n"+"/api2/v2/users/me"+"\n"+"0"
let shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1')
shasum.update(JSON.stringify(msg))
let hashed_string = shasum.digest('hex')
console.log(hashed_string)
// c838ca6f79551d828d6e4a810bd49c1df07b54a3
```

thanks for any help :)

Comment: Why `JSON.stringify(msg)`?

Comment: `msg !== JSON.stringify(msg)`. It adds `"` at the start and end

Comment: @Samathingamajig It does even more. It replaces newline with `\n`. `msg` has length 66 and `JSON.stringify(msg)` has length 71.

Comment: OMG, I really though I had to do something equivalent to the python's `encode("utf-8")` , that's why I added the `stringify` and `encodeURI` and other methods before, but no, without that, just works, what a journey, thanks for commenting, another dumb error that took me days to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `JSON.stringify` the message. `JSON.stringify` adds double quotes at the beginning and end and it replaces all newlines (and most other whitespace characters) with two characters `\n`. `msg` has length 66 and `JSON.stringify(msg)` has length 71. This code generates the expected SHA1 value:

```
const crypto = require('crypto') // maybe another library that works in browser? 
const msg = "6NmByERB9ZDJX9OKDtIzpGl8ei7KBiYI"+"\n"+"1623776851607"+"\n"+"/api2/v2/users/me"+"\n"+"0"
let shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1')
shasum.update(msg)
let hashed_string = shasum.digest('hex')
console.log(hashed_string)
```

Here you can see the differences between `msg` and `JSON.stringify(msg)`:

```js
const msg = "6NmByERB9ZDJX9OKDtIzpGl8ei7KBiYI"+"\n"+"1623776851607"+"\n"+"/api2/v2/users/me"+"\n"+"0"

console.log(msg)
console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
console.log(msg.length)
console.log(JSON.stringify(msg).length);
console.log(JSON.stringify(msg) === msg);
```